# Openfin Automation - How to run a single test case

Tags: jestjs, webdriver, openfin

I'm using @openfin/automation-cli v1.1.3 with jest runner and the default webdriver. I can run test suites but do not know how to run a single test case from the command line. (I know about it.only)